# javascript /innerHTML / html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function - triggered with onclick -, that is dynamically changing 4 pics in the current page. But where i have troubles, is the displayed set of picture is clickable too, and should display the picture in lightbox.

So 2 buttons, corresponding to 2 sets of pictures, a click call a  function which changes the innerHTML of the table where the set of pictures is displayed.

Sadly, the lightbox is not processed.

Any idea what's wrong and how i can do this ?

```
    javascript: 
my_onclick(){ document.getElementByID("content").innerHTML = '<a rel="lightbox" href="pic/1.jpg"><img src="pic/1.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px;" /></a>';

    html:
<table><tr><td id="content"></td></tr></table>

Lightbox (slimbox.js)

    var Lightbox = {

    init: function(options){
        this.options = $extend({
            resizeDuration: 400,
            resizeTransition: false,    // default transition
            initialWidth: 250,
            initialHeight: 250,
            animateCaption: true,
            showCounter: true
        }, options || {});

        this.anchors = [];
        $each(document.links, function(el){
            if (el.rel && el.rel.test(/^lightbox/i)){
                el.onclick = this.click.pass(el, this);
                this.anchors.push(el);
            }
        }, this);
        this.eventKeyDown = this.keyboardListener.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.eventPosition = this.position.bind(this);

        this.overlay = new Element('div', {'id': 'lbOverlay'}).injectInside(document.body);

        this.center = new Element('div', {'id': 'lbCenter', 'styles': {'width': this.options.initialWidth, 'height': this.options.initialHeight, 'marginLeft': -(this.options.initialWidth/2), 'display': 'none'}}).injectInside(document.body);
        this.image = new Element('div', {'id': 'lbImage'}).injectInside(this.center);
        this.prevLink = new Element('a', {'id': 'lbPrevLink', 'href': '#', 'styles': {'display': 'none'}}).injectInside(this.image);
        this.nextLink = this.prevLink.clone().setProperty('id', 'lbNextLink').injectInside(this.image);
        this.prevLink.onclick = this.previous.bind(this);
        this.nextLink.onclick = this.next.bind(this);

        this.bottomContainer = new Element('div', {'id': 'lbBottomContainer', 'styles': {'display': 'none'}}).injectInside(document.body);
        this.bottom = new Element('div', {'id': 'lbBottom'}).injectInside(this.bottomContainer);
        new Element('a', {'id': 'lbCloseLink', 'href': '#'}).injectInside(this.bottom).onclick = this.overlay.onclick = this.close.bind(this);
        this.caption = new Element('div', {'id': 'lbCaption'}).injectInside(this.bottom);
        this.number = new Element('div', {'id': 'lbNumber'}).injectInside(this.bottom);
        new Element('div', {'styles': {'clear': 'both'}}).injectInside(this.bottom);

        var nextEffect = this.nextEffect.bind(this);
        this.fx = {
            overlay: this.overlay.effect('opacity', {duration: 500}).hide(),
            resize: this.center.effects($extend({duration: this.options.resizeDuration, onComplete: nextEffect}, this.options.resizeTransition ? {transition: this.options.resizeTransition} : {})),
            image: this.image.effect('opacity', {duration: 500, onComplete: nextEffect}),
            bottom: this.bottom.effect('margin-top', {duration: 400, onComplete: nextEffect})
        };

        this.preloadPrev = new Image();
        this.preloadNext = new Image();
    },

    click: function(link){
        if (link.rel.length == 8) return this.show(link.href, link.title);

        var j, imageNum, images = [];
        this.anchors.each(function(el){
            if (el.rel == link.rel){
                for (j = 0; j < images.length; j++) if(images[j][0] == el.href) break;
                if (j == images.length){
                    images.push([el.href, el.title]);
                    if (el.href == link.href) imageNum = j;
                }
            }
        }, this);
        return this.open(images, imageNum);
    },

    show: function(url, title){
        return this.open([[url, title]], 0);
    },

    open: function(images, imageNum){
        this.images = images;
        this.position();
        this.setup(true);
        this.top = window.getScrollTop() + (window.getHeight() / 15);
        this.center.setStyles({top: this.top, display: ''});
        this.fx.overlay.start(0.8);
        return this.changeImage(imageNum);
    },

    position: function(){
        this.overlay.setStyles({'top': window.getScrollTop(), 'height': window.getHeight()});
    },

    setup: function(open){
        var elements = $A(document.getElementsByTagName('object'));
        elements.extend(document.getElementsByTagName(window.ie ? 'select' : 'embed'));
        elements.each(function(el){
            if (open) el.lbBackupStyle = el.style.visibility;
            el.style.visibility = open ? 'hidden' : el.lbBackupStyle;
        });
        var fn = open ? 'addEvent' : 'removeEvent';
        window[fn]('scroll', this.eventPosition)[fn]('resize', this.eventPosition);
        document[fn]('keydown', this.eventKeyDown);
        this.step = 0;
    },

    keyboardListener: function(event){
        switch (event.keyCode){
            case 27: case 88: case 67: this.close(); break;
            case 37: case 80: this.previous(); break;   
            case 39: case 78: this.next();
        }
    },

    previous: function(){
        return this.changeImage(this.activeImage-1);
    },

    next: function(){
        return this.changeImage(this.activeImage+1);
    },

    changeImage: function(imageNum){
        if (this.step || (imageNum < 0) || (imageNum >= this.images.length)) return false;
        this.step = 1;
        this.activeImage = imageNum;

        this.bottomContainer.style.display = this.prevLink.style.display = this.nextLink.style.display = 'none';
        this.fx.image.hide();
        this.center.className = 'lbLoading';

        this.preload = new Image();
        this.preload.onload = this.nextEffect.bind(this);
        this.preload.src = this.images[imageNum][0];
        return false;
    },

    nextEffect: function(){
        switch (this.step++){
        case 1:
            this.center.className = '';
            this.image.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+this.images[this.activeImage][0]+')';
            this.image.style.width = this.bottom.style.width = this.preload.width+'px';
            this.image.style.height = this.prevLink.style.height = this.nextLink.style.height = this.preload.height+'px';

            this.caption.setHTML(this.images[this.activeImage][1] || '');
            this.number.setHTML((!this.options.showCounter || (this.images.length == 1)) ? '' : 'Image '+(this.activeImage+1)+' of '+this.images.length);

            if (this.activeImage) this.preloadPrev.src = this.images[this.activeImage-1][0];
            if (this.activeImage != (this.images.length - 1)) this.preloadNext.src = this.images[this.activeImage+1][0];
            if (this.center.clientHeight != this.image.offsetHeight){
                this.fx.resize.start({height: this.image.offsetHeight});
                break;
            }
            this.step++;
        case 2:
            if (this.center.clientWidth != this.image.offsetWidth){
                this.fx.resize.start({width: this.image.offsetWidth, marginLeft: -this.image.offsetWidth/2});
                break;
            }
            this.step++;
        case 3:
            this.bottomContainer.setStyles({top: this.top + this.center.clientHeight, height: 0, marginLeft: this.center.style.marginLeft, display: ''});
            this.fx.image.start(1);
            break;
        case 4:
            if (this.options.animateCaption){
                this.fx.bottom.set(-this.bottom.offsetHeight);
                this.bottomContainer.style.height = '';
                this.fx.bottom.start(0);
                break;
            }
            this.bottomContainer.style.height = '';
        case 5:
            if (this.activeImage) this.prevLink.style.display = '';
            if (this.activeImage != (this.images.length - 1)) this.nextLink.style.display = '';
            this.step = 0;
        }
    },

    close: function(){
        if (this.step < 0) return;
        this.step = -1;
        if (this.preload){
            this.preload.onload = Class.empty;
            this.preload = null;
        }
        for (var f in this.fx) this.fx[f].stop();
        this.center.style.display = this.bottomContainer.style.display = 'none';
        this.fx.overlay.chain(this.setup.pass(false, this)).start(0);
        return false;
    }
};

window.addEvent('domready', Lightbox.init.bind(Lightbox));
```

Comment: Can you please add in the name of the lightbox library or post it's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightbox script processes all the images at page load, so any images that you dynamically insert after page load will not be lightboxed. Look at the lightbox script and call whatever function processes images on page load after you have inserted the new images.

Comment: Thank you, i understand now. Sadly i fear i have to learn JS to change this.